# Executing shell program in Python without printing to screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

Is there a way that I can execute a shell program from Python, which prints its output to the screen, and read its output to a variable without displaying anything on the screen?

This sounds a little bit confusing, so maybe I can explain it better by an example.

Let's say I have a program that prints something to the screen when executed

```
bash> ./my_prog
bash> "Hello World"
```

When I want to read the output into a variable in Python, I read that a good approach is to use the `subprocess` module like so:

```
my_var = subprocess.check_output("./my_prog", shell=True)
```

With this construct, I can get the program's output into `my_var` (here `"Hello World"`), however it is also printed to the screen when I run the Python script. Is there any way to suppress this? I couldn't find anything in the `subprocess` documentation, so maybe there is another module I could use for this purpose?

EDIT:
I just found out that `commands.getoutput()` lets me do this. But is there also a way to achieve similar effects in `subprocess`? Because I was planning to make a Python3 version at some point.

---

EDIT2: Particular Example

Excerpt from the python script:

```
oechem_utils_path = "/soft/linux64/openeye/examples/oechem-utilities/"\
        "openeye/toolkits/1.7.2.4/redhat-RHEL5-g++4.3-x64/examples/"\
        "oechem-utilities/"

rmsd_path = oechem_utils_path + "rmsd"

for file in lMol2:
            sReturn = subprocess.check_output("{rmsd_exe} {rmsd_pars}"\
                 " -in {sIn} -ref {sRef}".format(rmsd_exe=sRmsdExe,\
                 rmsd_pars=sRmsdPars, sIn=file, sRef=sReference), shell=True)
    dRmsds[file] = sReturn
```

---

Screen Output (Note that not "everything" is printed to the screen, only a part of
the output, and if I use `commands.getoutput` everything works just fine:

```
/soft/linux64/openeye/examples/oechem-utilities/openeye/toolkits/1.7.2.4/redhat-RHEL5-g++4.3-x64/examples/oechem-utilities/rmsd: mols in: 1  out: 0
/soft/linux64/openeye/examples/oechem-utilities/openeye/toolkits/1.7.2.4/redhat-RHEL5-g++4.3-x64/examples/oechem-utilities/rmsd: confs in: 1  out: 0
/soft/linux64/openeye/examples/oechem-utilities/openeye/toolkits/1.7.2.4/redhat-RHEL5-g++4.3-x64/examples/oechem-utilities/rmsd - RMSD utility [OEChem 1.7.2]

/soft/linux64/openeye/examples/oechem-utilities/openeye/toolkits/1.7.2.4/redhat-RHEL5-g++4.3-x64/examples/oechem-utilities/rmsd: mols in: 1  out: 0
/soft/linux64/openeye/examples/oechem-utilities/openeye/toolkits/1.7.2.4/redhat-RHEL5-g++4.3-x64/examples/oechem-utilities/rmsd: confs in: 1  out: 0
```

Comment: Are you sure? Because `checkout_output` simply returns the output as a string, nothing is flushed on the screen.

Comment: Yes I am, I will post the exact in and output to my initial query in a few moments

Comment: I have added the particular issue under `EDIT2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to Ryan Haining's answer, you can also handle stderr to make sure nothing is printed to the screen:

```
 p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
out,err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: ahhh, I forgot the `stderr`! thank you, this solved my problem!

Comment: you could use `output = check_output(cmd, stderr=STDOUT)`, to capture both stdout and stderr in a single variable.

Answer (score 1):

If `subprocess.check_ouput` is not working for you, use a [Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) object and a `PIPE` to capture the program's output in Python.

```
prog = subprocess.Popen('./myprog', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = prog.communicate()[0]
```

the `.communicate()` method will wait for a program to finish execution and then return a tuple of `(stdout, stderr)` which is why you'll want to take the `[0]` of that.

If you also want to capture `stderr` then add `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to the creation of the `Popen` object.

If you wish to capture the output of `prog` while it is running instead of waiting for it to finish, you can call `line = prog.stdout.readline()` to read one line at a time.  Note that this will hang if there are no lines available until there is one.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that before and it still printed some of the output to the screen. Hm, maybe it's just a problem with this particular program and I will just go with `commands.getoutput`

Comment: @SebastianRaschka as I said in my answer, you can also capture `stderr` which is likely the cause of "some of the output" being printed

Comment: yes, thank you, just overlooked it somehow, since this output is just the "regular" output and not an "error" notification

Answer (score 0):

I always used [Subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), which gives you no output normally